# Syntax for overloaded template functions with lambda function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, overloading

I need help with the syntax for the following C++ (17) code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct st_a {
  int var;
};

struct st_b {
  double var;
};


void func(void(cb)(st_a)) {
  st_a a;
  a.var = 3;
  cb(a);
}

void func(void(cb)(st_b)) {
  st_b b;
  b.var = 4;
  cb(b);
}

class test {
public:
  test() {

    func([](st_a arg) { std::cout << arg.var; });
    
    func([this](st_a arg) { my_func_a(arg); });

    func([this](st_b arg) { my_func_b(arg); });

  }

  void my_func_a(st_a arg) {
    std::cout << arg.var;
  }

  void my_func_b(st_b arg) {
    std::cout << arg.var;
  }
};



int main(void)
{
  test t;
}
```

Unsurprisingly the compiler gives me

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘func(test::test()::<lambda(st_a)>)’
```

I attempted to rectify it using template functions, i.e.,

```
template<typename F>
void func(F cb) {
  st_a a;
  a.var = 3;
  cb(a);
}

template<typename F>
void func(F cb) {
  st_b b;
  b.var = 4;
  cb(b);
}
```

But this results in

```
error: redefinition of ‘template<class F> void func(F)’
```

...which is no surprise.

My question is how can I change the template parameters to specify the function argument?

### Follow up from analyzing replies

I forgot to mention that I'm chasing nanoseconds, so `std::function` is not an option.

The assembly output from Yksisarvinen's and max66's solutions is identical, branch-free, and very compact (the whole program compiles into 9 assembly instructions). The `std::function` assembly on the other hand contains page upon page of branches and function calls, which invalidates this approach from an execution speed prespective.

From a code readability perspective, perhaps `std::function` is the best option. In my opinion, the second best alternative is the one max66 presented, i.e

`template <typename F> auto func (F cb) -> decltype(cb(std::declval<st_a>()), void()) { ...; }`

this is also the best approach for portability (C++11) when compared to Yksisarvinen's solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: no-capture lambdas can decay to pointer functions. capture-lambda can't.

Comment: `void func(std::function<void (st_a)> cb)` ?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain the core issue with capturing lambda, but you can solve the problem without `std:function` by using some template metaprogramming with [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

```
template<typename F, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F, st_a>, bool> = true>
void func(F cb) {
  st_a a;
  a.var = 3;
  cb(a);
}

template<typename F, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F, st_b>, bool> = true>
void func(F cb) {
  st_b b;
  b.var = 4;
  cb(b);
}
```

With definitions as such, compiler will only generate first `func` if `F` can be invoked with argument of type `st_a` and second `func` if the argument can be invoked with argument of type `st_b`. It will probably break if both could be true at the same time (e.g. if you introduce inheritance between `st_a` and `st_b`).

[See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kOKkqg2pi8gz8tGv)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the lambdas defined here

```cpp
func([this](st_a arg) { my_func_a(arg); });
func([this](st_b arg) { my_func_b(arg); });
```

have captures.  You can think of a lambda as a class that implements `operator()`. Lambdas with captures have members in that class.

If you have a lambda with no captures, the compiler provides an implicit conversion to a function pointer, because this is essentially what it is.

If you have a lambda with captures, the compiler can not provide an implicit conversion because you would not be able to fit all these captures into a single pointer.

*(If you are interested in lambdas in C++, I'd recommend looking at Jason Turners "Weekly C++" episodes from which many are about lambdas. [This one talks about what lambdas are.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=br4tez2G9eM))*

The C++ standard library provides `std::function` which is some type-erasure magic that, honestly, I don't fully understand. (I remember watching a C++ Weekly episode about that, but I can't recall properly what it does.)

Anyways, by taking a `std::function` you get a small overhead and the standard library will just make everything work.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (almost equivalent to the `std::is_invocable_v` answer from Yksisarvinen, but working also before C++17) could be the following

```
template <typename F>
auto func (F cb) -> decltype( cb(std::declval<st_a>()), void() )
 {
   st_a a{3};
   cb(a);
 }

template <typename F>
auto func (F cb) -> decltype( cb(std::declval<st_b>()), void() )
 {
   st_b b{4};
   cb(b);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a lambda function to something that expects a function pointer, so the type doesn't match. I would suggest changing `func` to accept a `std::function` as callback, so that you can pass a lambda to it

```cpp
#include <functional>

void func(std::function<void(st_a)> cb) {
  st_a a;
  a.var = 3;
  cb(a);
}

void func(std::function<void(st_b)> cb) {
  st_b b;
  b.var = 4;
  cb(b);
}
```